# How can I add an applet to MATE from the terminal?

Tags: 12.04, mate

How could I add an applet to the MATE panel from the Terminal using `mateconftool-2`. I'm specifically asking for DockBarX, but I'd like to add other applets as well (MATEnu, Notification area and Clock).

What I want to do is instead of manually right-clicking the panel, opening the Add to Panel window and selecting the applet, do this from the command line.

How can this be done with `mateconftool-2`?

**Edit:** I've found that it can be done with this `/usr/lib/mate-panel/mate-panel-add` however I don't know yet how I can add an applet with it.

This for example would add a gedit *launcher* to the *panel*:

```
/usr/lib/mate-panel/mate-panel-add --launcher=/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop
```

I want to do that *but* instead of a launcher an applet.

```
/usr/lib/mate-panel/mate-panel-add --applet=
```

- Something like this but I don't know how to add the rest (in this case call the DockbarX applet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As MATE is a fork of GNOME2 and most of its components are simply the old GNOME2 with their names changed, I'm assuming `mate-panel-add` works the same as `gnome-panel-add` used to. You need to do something along the lines of:

```
/usr/lib/gnome-panel/mate-panel-add --applet=OAFIID:MATE_DockBarXApplet --panel=top_panel_screen0 --position=500
```

Where the value of `--panel=` is one of the panels found in `mateconf` found with something like:

```
mateconftool-2 --all-dirs /apps/panel/toplevels
```

The `--applet` identifier can be found in the `/usr/lib/matecomponent/servers/` directory. In this particular case, in the `MATE_DockBarXApplet.server` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I have a question though, for example  how do I know what to put in the `position=` identifier? are those pixels? or is it something else?