# How can I remove all the applets from a MATE panel?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, panel, mate

I'd like to know How can I remove all the applets from a given panel in MATE (in my case the bottom panel) from the command-line.

The panel should be left in a clean state, meaning no applets just the panel. Pretty much the opposite of [what I did here](https://askubuntu.com/q/229511/4203). I believe [the answer I got here](https://askubuntu.com/q/229511/4203) should have some clues of what to do, but then again I'm not good at scripting.

How would I go about doing it?.

Comment: LOL, another 500? Joking. I will update a script here. Happy Holiday.

Comment: Hell yeah, serves for motivation I suppose :P, Thanks. Happy Holidays.

Comment: LOL, done!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably need more help with MATE though.

Comment: I will always try :) I have multiple accounts using mate as default WM now, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually the same [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/231708/106529). But WITHOUT the panel deletion part. I also change *DEL_PANEL* to *TARGET_PANEL* to avoid confusion.

**TARGET_PANEL** is the panel name of panel to be altered.

```
#!/bin/bash

PANEL_PATH="${HOME}/.mateconf/apps/panel"
TARGET_PANEL='bottom_panel_screen0'

    echo 'DEBUG: Panel Path' ${PANEL_PATH}
    echo 'DEBUG: Panel to be altered' ${TARGET_PANEL}

# - APPLETS
# -- Identify applet to be deleted

cd ${PANEL_PATH}/applets
DEL_APPLET=`grep -r ${TARGET_PANEL} *|cut -d\/ -f1`

    echo 'DEBUG: DEL_APPLET' ; for i in ${DEL_APPLET} ; do echo -e "DEBUG: \t${i}" ; done

# -- Get old applet id list

APPLET_ID_LIST_OLD=`mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/applet_id_list | cut -d\[ -f2 | cut -d\] -f1 | sed 's/,/ /g'`

    echo 'DEBUG: Old applet_id_list' ${APPLET_ID_LIST_OLD}

# -- Generate new applet id list

APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW=''
for i in ${APPLET_ID_LIST_OLD}
do
    if [[ "$DEL_APPLET" != *"${i}"* ]]
    then
        echo -e "DEBUG: \tKeep ${i}"
        APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW="${APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW} ${i}"
    else
        echo -e "DEBUG: \tDel  ${i}"
        # -- Delete applet folder
        rm -rf ${PANEL_PATH}/applets/${i}
    fi
done
APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW="[`echo ${APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW} | sed 's/ /,/g'`]"

# -- Apply new applet id list
mateconftool-2 -s /apps/panel/general/applet_id_list -t list --list-type=string "${APPLET_ID_LIST_NEW}"

    echo 'DEBUG: New applet_id_list' `mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/applet_id_list`


# - OBJECTS
# -- Identify object to be deleted

cd ${PANEL_PATH}/objects
DEL_OBJECT=`grep -r ${TARGET_PANEL} *|cut -d\/ -f1`

    echo 'DEBUG: DEL_OBJECT' ; for i in ${DEL_OBJECT} ; do echo -e "DEBUG: \t${i}" ; done

# -- Get old object id list

OBJECT_ID_LIST_OLD=`mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/object_id_list | cut -d\[ -f2 | cut -d\] -f1 | sed 's/,/ /g'`

    echo 'DEBUG: Old object_id_list' ${OBJECT_ID_LIST_OLD}

# -- Generate new object id list

OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW=''
for i in ${OBJECT_ID_LIST_OLD}
do
    if [[ "$DEL_OBJECT" != *"${i}"* ]]
    then
        echo -e "DEBUG:\tKeep ${i}"
        OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW="${OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW} ${i}"
    else
        echo -e "DEBUG:\tDel  ${i}"
        # -- Delete object folder
        rm -rf ${PANEL_PATH}/objects/${i}
    fi
done
OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW="[`echo ${OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW} | sed 's/ /,/g'`]"

# -- Apply new object id list
mateconftool-2 -s /apps/panel/general/object_id_list -t list --list-type=string "${OBJECT_ID_LIST_NEW}"

    echo 'DEBUG: New applet_id_list' `mateconftool-2 -g /apps/panel/general/object_id_list`
```